# MS Excel 2016 - Search a ID in Column A and compare corresponding Values in Column B and get condition based result in Column C

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have excel with different columns. Column A have Unique and duplicate ID's while Column B have corresponding values. I need a formula where i can search individual ID in column 1 and get different values in column 2 for this ID and then use a condition to extract required value.

```
Col A Col B
ID1   R
ID2   0
ID1   6
ID1   R
ID3   1
ID2   6
ID4   T
```

In Column C i wanted this result [Requirement here is if we get values 0,1,2,5 along with R or 6 or T then Value is No..if we get only R,6,T together or Individually then Value is Yes]

```
For  Column C
ID 1    Yes
ID 2    No
ID 1    Yes
ID 1    Yes
ID 3    No
ID 2    No
ID 4    Yes
```

This works in Pivot table but i need in formula as this part of a bigger Conditional formatting formula.[Tried Index but it only searches first value so not much useful]

Comment: Use index with match or vlookup - what functions / formulae have you tried?

Comment: Index/Match - But it only shows the first search. Example For ID 2 once it reads value 0 then it will ignore the Value R .Pivot Table solves the purpose but i have to extract the ID's from Pivot and then Match with Main column separately.

Comment: Have you searched this site or Stack Overflow - there are several examples of this type of application? I don't have chance to look now sorry...

Comment: Searched a lot but they are not close what i required,

Comment: You don't say what should happen if 0, 1, 2 or 5 occur without R, 6 or T. Or what should happen if none of those values are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with is a little cumbersome. It could be done with a single very long formula in columns C, but to make it more readable (and easier to debug), I have stored two intermediate numbers in columns D and E.

The following assumes that the date you provided in your question is entered in the range A1:B7.

In D1, enter: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,0)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,2)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,5)`

That will return the number of times the ID in A1 has a corresponding value in column B of 0, 1, 2 or 5.

And in E1, enter: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,"R")+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,6)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,$A1,$B$1:$B$7,"T")`

That will return the number of times the ID in A1 has a corresponding value in column B of "R", 6 or "T".

Now in C1, enter: `=IF(E1=0,"Error",IF(D1>0,"No","Yes"))` This returns "Error" if no "R", 6 or "T" is found (you didn't say what to do in this case); otherwise it returns "No" if a 0, 1, 2 or 5 is found and "Yes" if not found.

Comment: @ Blackwood , Many Thanks this worked,slows down excel little bit though ; ) .If there are no "R", 6 or "T" is found then its "NO"..i modified the final expression anyway.Now i will use this for another column with Date as well. Thanks again.